# How can I stop HighCharts drawing an extra 'tick' outside the graph area?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I stop HighCharts drawing an extra 'tick' outside the graph area?

JS Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezpo47ua/1/

[image]

I'm not sure if it relates to the tick positioner or not as this doesn't seem to cause any problems when there are more data points.

```
 tickPositioner: function () {
        var result = [];                        
        var maxDate = new Date('2015/09/25'); 

        for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++) 
            result.push(Date.UTC(maxDate.getFullYear(), maxDate.getMonth(), i));

        result.info = {
            unitName: "day",
            higherRanks: {}
        };

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the difference in your timezone and utc timezone. Seem like 25 sep in your case may be 24 sep in utc.

**Update**
in your fiddle your code

```
min: new Date('2015/09/25').getTime()
```

returns 1443119400000 in timestamps which is equals to GMT: Thu, 24 Sep 2015 18:30:00 GMT.

Comment: I can see what you mean, and if I run it here in my GMT timezone, get 24th at 23:00, but no matter how I try and adapt my code to make it 'not care' about time zones, I still get the same results and the extra tick :(

Comment: Got it...  Updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezpo47ua/2/  - thanks. Not sure if this is the best way though. Do you think this can be simplified?